# JavaScript TypeError: contract is not a function

Tags: javascript, contract

So I have two .js files.
This is the contract function inside contract.js file:

```
function contract(preList, post, f) {
// ***YOUR CODE HERE***
     for(let i in preList){
       if (! preList[i]){
        throw " Contract violation in position 1." +
        "Expected number but received four.  Blame -> Top-level code";
       }
     }
      if(!post){
       throw " Contract violation in position 1." +
       "Expected number but returned undefined. Blame -> brokenMult";
      }
     return f;
    }
```

I am trying to involving above contract function:

```
var contracts = require('contracts');
var contract = contracts.contract;
var isNumber = contracts.isNumber;

   var mult = contract(
     [isNumber, isNumber],
     isNumber,
     function mult (x, y) {
     return x+y;
     });

   var brokenMult = contract(
     [isNumber, isNumber],
     isNumber,
     function brokenMult(x, y) {
     return undefined;
     });
```

This is where exporting contract function inside contracts.js

```
    module.exports = {
      contract: contract,
      any: any,
      isBoolean: isBoolean,
      isDefined: isDefined,
      isNumber: isNumber,
      isPositive: isPositive,
      isNegative: isNegative,
      isInteger: Number.isInteger,
      isString: isString,
      and: and,
      or: or,
      not: not,
      };
```

For somehow reason **TypeError: contract is not a function**

Comment: Have you exported it?

Comment: Yeah. I did I link two files together using $npm link.

Comment: Thats something else.

Comment: I just check the codes. exporting already been done. I added the code block where contract exported

Comment: What does `console.log(require("contracts"))` return?

Comment: it returns a bunch of environment, filters and formats.

Comment: And also `contracts` ? Otherwise the importing went wrong

Comment: console.log(contracts) returns the same as console.log(require("contracts")).

Comment: I mean does it really import what you wanted?